# A formula which relate spring constant to its physical properties like length and area of cross section

Tags: classical-mechanics, capacitance, spring

I know spring is a mechanical analogue of capacitor. And length of a spring is equivalent to plate seperation of capacitor. So what is the mechanical equivalent of area of cross section of capacitor in spring? And is there a similar formula like $C=\epsilon_0 {A \over d}$  for spring constant $k$.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example is that the stiffness of an elastic rod is
$$
k = \frac{EA}{L_0},
$$
where $A$ is the cross-sectional area of the rod, $L_0$ is its unstretched length, and $E$ is the [Young's modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_modulus) of the material of the rod.

Note, however, that this is only for a rod that stretches uniformly along its length;  think of a rubber band rather than a coiled spring.  When a spring stretches, the coils of wire bend slightly relative to each other, rather than the wire simply stretching.

Comment: @RahulR In other words, a spring is MUCH more complicated in relating $k$ to the shape parameters of the spring. The material of the spring wire is primarily in a twisting (torsion) motion rather than axial.